# Understanding fixed error: Sending NSError *const __strong* to parameter

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, compiler-errors

In writing my original question, I inadvertently fixed my problem. I'd like to understand why my changes caused the fix.

I wrote a class method that accepts a `NSString` and an `NSError **`. The method returns `YES` if the string is a valid password in my application, and `NO` if it isn't. In the event that `NO` is returned, the `NSError` passed by reference is set inside the method.

Here's the validation method:

```
@interface PasswordValidator

+ (BOOL)isValid:(NSString *)password error:(NSError **)error {

    NSError *err = nil;

    if (!password || password.length < 1) {
        err = [NSError errorWithDomain:...];
    }

    // Rest of logic omitted for brevity

    if (err) {
        if (error) {
            *error = err;
        }
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
@end
```

In my test, I was mistakenly attempting to check for the existence of the `NSError` object like so:

```
    it(@"should set error if password is nil", ^{
        NSError *error;
        expect([PasswordValidator isValid:nil error:&error]).toNot.beNil();
    });
```

Ignoring the fact that the test contains a logical error, the code caused the compiler to complain with the error: `Sending NSError *const __strong* to parameter of type 'NSError *__autoreleasing* changes retain/release properters of pointer`.

After updating the test so that the invocation of `PasswordValidator:isValid:error` occurred on a separate line, the error disappeared:

```
    // The test below did not cause compilation issues.
    it(@"should return NO if password is nil", ^{
        NSError *error;
        [HAYPasswordValidator isValid:nil error:&error];
        expect(error).toNot.beNil();
    });
```

My question is, why was the compiler originally complaining and what was it about separating the method invocation onto a separate line that resolved the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What test harness are you using?   If that `expect()` function is actually a macro that is wrapping the expression in a block, then that might likely cause the compiler to complain in that fashion.

**However**, *your fixed test is wrong*.

You can't test the error for `nil`/`non-nil` directly.   `error` will only be set to a defined value if the method returns `NO` (or `nil`, typically -- whatever indicates an error).  Then and only then will `error` be defined.

Consider the implementation of your `isValid:error:` method.  If there is no error, the `error` parameter isn't touched.  If `error` was uninitialized on entry to that method, it'll still be uninitialized in the success case and your test case may likely fail when it shouldn't if you only test `error` itself.

Comment: Your last paragraph seems a little deceptive given that in the code he shows `error` is initialized to nil (assuming he's using ARC). Isn't the issue more that called method is free to store an error object in there even in a success case? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @JesseRusak In my "fixed test", I've assumed that the method will return `NO` because the input string is `nil`. I've written another test, not included above, that asserts that the method does in fact return `NO` for this `nil` case. Are you saying that I should assert that `NO` is returned before asserting that `error` is not nil?

Comment: @Bibs I think it's probably OK if you *know* it will fail, but it does look weird to my eyes to ignore the return value and look at the error presence alone.

Comment: @JesseRusak If `error` is non-NULL and there was no error, the assignment of `*error = err` doesn't happen.  `error` remains uninitialized in the caller.

And, no, it is **not OK** to implement this pattern with the assumption described.   It'll leak out from there and it doesn't actually test correct behavior (that the error is set to a known value when *the method also returns an indication of an error*).

Comment: @bbum Thanks, I'm happy to defer to your sense of whether this test is a bad idea. To be clear, all I was trying to say above is that in the test harness he shows, `error` *is* initialized to nil before calling `isValid:error:`.

Comment: @JesseRusak No worries -- I'm admittedly pedantic, but that comes from 25 years of fixing bugs oft caused by such inconsistencies. :)   I must be missing something, though. There is `NSError *err = nil;` but not declarations of `NSError *error;` come without initialization.  Now, ARC *will* zero them out, but if that were a call into a framework `-foo:error:` method, there are cases where the `error` pointer will be modified in a non-error-returning case (sometimes left as a dangling pointer).

Comment: Yep, I think we're saying the same thing; the exact code shown will work because of ARC's initialization of error, but it's violating the language conventions to write code that tests error pointers rather than return values. (And many innocent-looking changes could easily break this test.)

Answer (score 1):

An NSError** parameter is actually an NSError *__autoreleasing* parameter. If you pass &error, the compiler will create a local NSError* __autoreleasing variable, pass that to the method, and store the result into the error. It's a bit complicated, but most people never notice.

I would suspect that the expect macro or function does some complicated stuff that makes this to complicated for the compiler, and it complains. You might check the preprocessor output to see what is actually compiled. I wouldn't be sure where the "const" from the error message comes from.

Answer (score 0):

You can also encounter this error is you try and capture an NSError ** variable in a block. Capturing __autoreleasing variables is a no can do amigo. All that is required is to redeclare the NSError ** inside the block.